# Disable button click if input field is empty using angular 4

Tags: angular

I have a search box and a search button. I need to disable button until user provides the search term, but the button gets disable always.  I have following the code:

```
 <input type='text' [(ngModel)]='listFilter' />
 <button [disabled]="!listFilter" class="btn btn-primary"(click)='OnSearch(listFilter)'>
      Search
 </button>
```

What's wrong here? I'm using angular 4

Comment: `[disabled]="!listFilter.length"` ?

Comment: Can't reproduce https://plnkr.co/edit/LvkkdVw14SdIQLq2y6tb?p=preview

Comment: i checked on plnkr and it is working on plnkr but don't work with my code

Comment: Please provide your component logic and check the log for errors. If it isn't working it is probably a problem somewhere else in the template or with the component logic.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add name property inside the input tag.

```
 <input type='text' [(ngModel)]='listFilter' name="listFilter"/>
            <button [disabled]="!listFilter" class="btn btn-primary" (click)='OnSearch(listFilter)'>Search</button>
```

Comment: it gets disabled on load but doesn't get enabled when input get some text

Comment: It would work if you remove the **click** event. I think something happening on the click event. check it out.

Comment: nope..i removed click event and still same behavior

Comment: Awesome-st answer!

Answer (score 5):

You must use a **template reference variable**!

To do this, you can use either **ref-prefix** or **#prefix**. In your example, you will have to modify it like this:

```
<input ref-filter type='text' [(ngModel)]='listFilter' />
<button [disabled]="!filter.value" class="btn btn-primary" (click)='OnSearch(listFilter)'>
 Search 
</button>
```

A model reference variable (#varRef) is not the same as a model input variable (variable let), as you might see in a * ngFor. The scope of a reference variable is the entire model. Do not set the same variable name more than once in the same model. The execution value will be unpredictable.

- More documentation here : https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax

Comment: **Note**: If your button status is not updated as soon as user types in the input field, this is due to Angular not triggering change detection on template variable change. You can workaround this issue by adding an event listener to your input field like this:

    `<input ref-filter type='text' (keyup)='true' />`

Answer (score 1):

```
<input ref-filter type='text' [(ngModel)]='listFilter' />
<button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="listFilter === ''"(click)="ClearText()">Reset User</button>
```

TS:

```
listFilter='';
ClearText(){
this.listFilter='';

}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.